# Need to hide the select option

Tags: jquery, html, select

**Edit** I think this what the OP meant

i have three select boxes with each 5 similar options. when I select an option from any of the select boxes it should disappear from the other two select boxes.

i have done work here js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/x66EN/13/

**Note:** Again select an option from any of the select boxes. the hidden option should display in the other two select boxes.

Comment: I've edited your post, but I'm not 100% sure if that's exactly what you want. Let me know if it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var sbox = $('select.selectArea[name=fromBox]');
    $('select.selectArea').change(function() {
        var val = this.value,
            allVals = [];
        sbox.each(function() {
            allVals.push(this.value);
        });
        sbox.each(function(index, sel) {
           $('option:hidden', this).show();
           $('option', this).map(function(i, x) {
                if(this.value != '0' && $.inArray(this.value, allVals) != -1) {
                   $(this).hide();
                }
           });
        });
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thesystemrestart/kGHH6/11/)**

Comment: @Mr.T.K please check the new Demo

Comment: thank you, But Again select an option from any of the select boxes. the hidden option should display in the other two select boxes. is there any solutions

Comment: I have tried but unable to display hidden options of the other two select boxes. Is there any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x66EN/20/)**? It doesn't remove the elements as you select them, it just disables them. This way if the user changes their mind, they can go back and make changes.

jQuery:

```
$('.selectArea').change(function() {
    var ary = new Array();
    $('.selectArea option:selected').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0 && $(this).val() != 0) {
            ary.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $('.selectArea option').each(function() {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), ary) > -1) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});​
```